# HTACCESS redirect one folder to another

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this URL: `http://example.com/ipclaw/admin`

If this url will be entered by any of the user it should be redirected to  `http://example.com/ipclaw/admin/login`

This is possible with `.htaccess`. I did googling but without success. Let me know if any of you have found this solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick (change the result code if necessary):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ipclaw/admin$ /ipclaw/admin/login
```

Answer (score 1):

This `.htaccess` should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/ipclaw/admin$ http://example.com/ipclaw/admin/login [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible without .htacess.
In the admin folder, create a file name and it index.php (http://example.com/ipclaw/admin/index.php)
Then you simply redirect to login directory using header in PHP:
`<?php
header("location: http://example.com/ipclaw/admin/login/index.php");
?>`

That should work just fine. No .htaccess though.

Answer (score 0):

## Permanent URL redirect

```
Redirect 301 "/ipclaw/admin " "http://domain.com/ipclaw/admin/login "
```